# Downloading an mp3 file from url

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that can download music files.

How to download mp3 file in android from a URL and save it in SD card??

I use this code but `lenghtOfFile` always `<=350`:

```
 String fileUrl = (String) params[0];
                path = (String) params[1];
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                int count;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection .connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                    int lenghtOfFile = connection .getContentLength();

                    // downlod the file
                    input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    output = new FileOutputStream(path);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
```

url files :

```
http://snd1.tebyan.net/1391/12/08_Khaneh_D_117323.mp3
http://snd1.tebyan.net/1393/12/100_Pedar_Va_Madar_D_148797.mp3
and .....
```

**update :**

```
int code= connection.getResponseCode();\\302
String _result= connection.getResponseMessage();\\ found
```

**note :**

Files do download in `Samsung Galaxy S3`, but files do not download in `Samsung tablet N8000`

Comment: I'd look at the actual response- are you sure you're getting a status 200 (connection worked and the url was found)?

Comment: your Url's aren't working !

Comment: connection.getResponseCode = 302 and connection.getResponseMessage = "found"

Comment: update.... files download in Samsung Galaxy S3 but files not download in Samsung tablet N8000

Answer (score 0):

You could implement HMTL5 and do it from there, might need some JS...

Answer (score 0):

for 302 response ,you need `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` to follow it. before `connection.connect()`

Comment: `String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");` request this new url again.